# How location changes in Android 11 will affect background requests?

Tags: android

I have an app that requests the user's location every 5 minutes and then maps their path.

To my understanding, with Android 11, Google changed how background location requests are handled. I have several questions about how this will affect my app:

1. Can I continue getting background location updates every 5 minutes?
2. If not, is there anything I can do to keep doing so?
3. When a new user downloads my app, what is the process of requesting background location permissions starting with Android 11?

I'm reading [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location) that in Android 11:

> On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, however, the system dialog doesn't include the Allow all the time option. Instead, users must enable background location on a settings page, as shown in figure 3.

Does this mean that unless the user selects "Allow all the time", I won't ever be able to get the user's location in the background?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

declare the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission in your app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```